# Key that yields multiple Results

Tags: java, hash

I'm pretty new to programming so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I was wondering if there was a type of data that returns (possibly) more than one answer per key. For example:

`TestType<int,String> test = new TestType<int,String>();`

So if you typed, test.getKey(1), you could get {"hello","this","is","a","test"}.

Basically, is there a type of data that can return multiple answers, sort of like a HashMap and List combined?

Comment: Actually, it's an excellent question.

Answer (score 5):

Not in standard Java. However, you can use the Guava [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) collection type. There are other libraries that also provide a multi-map collection.

If for some reason you don't want to use a third-party library, you can also roll your own data structure. However, it is definitely reinventing the wheel and it's a bit of a pain. You would define `test` to be a `Map<Integer, Set<String>>` and then write access methods to initialize the key entry with an empty set under appropriate conditions.

Note that Java does not allow primitive types (e.g., `int`, as you are using) to be used as generic type parameter values. You'll have to use `Integer`. Because of autoboxing, you can still use `test.get(1)` to retrieve the values stored under the key `1`.

Comment: why are you use `set` instead of `List`

Comment: @Samir - It depends on the desired semantics, of course. While I used Set, a List might indeed be better for OP's application. If the order of the values was important, then a List would be the right type. If the order was not important but multiplicity mattered, then a Multiset might be more appropriate. If neither order nor multiplicity of values mattered (a very common case), then a Set would be the best match. Guava Multimap uses Collection, with sub-interfaces for more specific value collection types.

Comment: Just to clarify, Guava provides `Multimap` (for generic collections), with subtypes `ListMultimap` and `SetMultimap` for the different use cases.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - Exactly what I was trying to say. Thanks for the clarification. It's interesting to note that while Guava has Multiset (a.k.a. bag), it does not have a subtype MultisetMultimap (i.e., mapping a key to a bag). If that's what's needed, you're back to rolling your own.

Comment: `MultisetMultimap` just doesn't have enough demand for us to make a serious investment in it, but `Multimaps.newMultimap` is sort of an approximation.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) from [apache commons collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/), and its specific implementation [MultiHashMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html)

You could also use a `Map<Integer,List<String>>` - as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is called a *multimap*, there are several implementations in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and another one in Apache commons [collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html).

Comment: Out of curiosity since this kind of anwer pops up very often.Why would one introduce a dependency to a third-party library just for use of a single data structure and nothing else?

Comment: @user384706: Getting familiar with third-party libraries is important - many things you'd want to implement already exist, and getting to know them is always good. Also, apache is considered a reliable 3rd party, and its components are widely used and thus widely tested.

Comment: @amit:I understand what you are saying but if one introduces libraries so easily you end up with a rather big application even for trivial functionality.Not sure if this is the same case everywhere but my boss wouldn't like extra 4MB for a lib just to use 1 data structure

Comment: @user384706 ask yourself: how hard would it be to implement the data structure? if it's simple enough, then write it yourself. If it's complex, and would need extensive testing, then you're better off using an implementation from a well-known library, even if that means adding a new dependency to your code

Answer (score 0):

Java does not offer a `multimap` since it is not used frequently (their statement). But SUN offers a small example on how to create a multimap yourself using a `Map` and a `List` as follows:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

You can see an example here in [Java Collections/Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html). Check the paragraph on multimaps for example code

Answer (score 0):

Amit's on the right track.  You can also create a class for the answer. This could help you increase encapsulation.

```
Map<Integer, MyAnswer>
```

where MyAnswer could include attributes for the data you wish to manage.  Implementing your own class here gives you a world of possibilities.